# Next occurrence of search pattern (Panels)

Tags: phpstorm

When you type something in Project or Database panels search pointer moves to the most fitting names. Can I choose between found matches using a shortcut?
Tab key isn't work in this case.
[image: example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use <kbd>Arrow Up</kbd> and <kbd>Arrow Down</kbd> keys.

Comment: Oh my god, I was so blind )) Thank you.