# How to move to next match

Tags: webstorm

I can search in the list of entries like this:

[image]

How do I proceed to the next match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use usual <kbd>Arrow Up</kbd> / <kbd>Arrow Down</kbd> keys for navigating between speed search matches.

*(just in case)* **NOTE:** Such search is performed on already opened/expanded nodes only -- it will not search in closed nodes or expand them for you.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.3/speed-search-in-the-tool-windows.html

---

P.S. https://stackoverflow.com/a/24929227/783119